# Stop send specific email notification for specific users in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I want to stop send Woocommerce email for specific user/email. this is my example code to stop send email when order is completed.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'ieo_ignore_function', 10, 2);

function ieo_ignore_function($headers, $email_id, $order) {
    $list = 'admin@example.com,cs@example.com';
    $user_email = (method_exists( $order, 'get_billing_email' ))? $order->get_billing_email(): $order->billing_email;
    $email_class = wc()->mailer();
    if($email_id == 'customer_completed_order'){
        if(stripos($list, $user_email)!==false){
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
        }
    }
}
```

But WP keep send the email. I try to search in Woocommerce docs and source (github) and Stackoverflow also but still cant solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example "Customer completed order" notification is disable for specific customer email addresses:

```
// Disable "Customer completed order" for specifics emails
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'completed_email_recipient_customization', 10, 2 );
function completed_email_recipient_customization( $recipient, $order ) {
    // Disable "Customer completed order
    if( is_a('WC_Order', $order) && in_array($order->get_billing_email(), array('jack@mail.com','emma@mail.com') ) ){
        $recipient = '';
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

> **Note:** A filter hook needs **always to return** the filtered main function argument

---

It can also be done from **User IDs** like:

```
// Disable "Customer completed order" for specifics User IDs
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'completed_email_recipient_customization', 10, 2 );
function completed_email_recipient_customization( $recipient, $order ) {
    // Disable "Customer completed order
    if( is_a('WC_Order', $order) && in_array($order->get_customer_id(), array(25,87) ) ){
        $recipient = '';
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

Similar: [Stop specific customer email notification based on payment methods in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361845/stop-specific-customer-email-notification-based-on-payment-methods-in-woocommerc/53362327#53362327)

Comment: i see you often answer WP question, you are really WP master my friend.

Comment: where i can find this parameter in docs? `woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order`

Comment: I have updated my answer … This hook is a composite hook: [`woocommerce_email_recipient_{$this->id}`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email.html#351) …

Comment: excellent, i read that class before but didnt notice if that function can be used in my purpose.

Comment: @plonknimbuzz I have added an additional code that do the same from user Ids instead of emails

Answer (score 0):

While answer above is working, this seems to be more straighforward solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'completed_email_recipient_customization', 10, 2 );
function completed_email_recipient_customization( $recipient, $order ) {
    if( in_array($recipient, ['some@email2block.com', 'another@email2block.com'] ) ) {
        $recipient = '';
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```